# why is FORMAT not working with expandproperty

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to check if the latest row in the table was added at the current time using the following script check:

```
$updateTime = "SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT([UPDATE_TIME], 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') FROM [dbo].[$Table] ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC" |
              Select -ExpandProperty UPDATE_TIME;
```

Before adding format, the expand property was working very well as intended getting me the latest UPDATE_TIME value

```
$updateTime = "SELECT TOP 1 [UPDATE_TIME] FROM [dbo].[$Table] ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC" |
              Select -ExpandProperty UPDATE_TIME;
```

[image: withoutFORMATworking]

However, when I added `FORMAT` to the query, it results in this error:

> Select : Property "UPDATE_TIME" cannot be found.
>
> - ... ble] ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC" | Select -ExpandProperty UPDATE_TIME;

I need to use `FORMAT` because I want to ignore the seconds, or if there is away i can ignore a 1 second difference between the `UPDATE_TIME` value and `Get-Date` value, that would be even better.

```
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('M/d/yyyy h:mm tt')

if ($updateTime -eq $today) {
    Write-Host "`r`n generated successfully at [ $updateTime ]"
} else {
    Write-Host "`r`n NOT generated at [ $today ]"
}
```

With FORMAT but not expand property, i get this output:
[image: withFormatNoexpandproperty]

Comment: `"SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC"` is a string. Why would there suddenly be a property `UPDATE_TIME` on that string for `Select-Object` to expand?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers not sure if i understood your comment...expand property is needed to get the UPDATE_TIME value. it clearly works in the query without FORMAT

Comment: You're omitting a step in your post. There *has* to be a portion of your script where you're executing that query and assigning the result to `$updateTime`.

Comment: @alroc ohhhh yes, i didnt include the query function if thats hwat youre referring to. I didnt want to make the post too long and didnt think the execution itself is important. now i see what Ansgar meant

Comment: @Cataster the execution is *critical* to helping you figure this out. You're asking for help on the `select-object` but we can't see what that object is because of it.

Comment: @alroc my bad, i was advised in the past not to make posts too long/detailed.

Comment: @Cataster that's generally good advice, but when you self-edit to the point where the question makes no sense and cannot be answered, it's counter to the goals of the site. You need to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your issue.

Comment: @alroc understood. ill be mindful of this in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your PowerShell console auto-execute strings as SQL queries? PowerShell doesn't normally do that.

Anyway, assuming that your PowerShell instance actually works that way, using the `FORMAT()` function (or other functions) changes the title of the result column, which in turn becomes the name of the respective property of the output object(s). Because of that the property `UPDATE_TIME` doesn't exist on those object and thus cannot be expanded.

You need to define a column name to fix that:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT(...) AS UPDATE_TIME ...
```

Comment: YES! this is exactly what I needed!! AS UPDATE_TIME